# Python: Number ranges that are extremely large?

Tags: python, input, long-integer

```
val = long(raw_input("Please enter the maximum value of the range:")) + 1
start_time = time.time()
numbers = range(0, val)
shuffle(numbers)
```

I cannot find a simple way to make this work with extremely large inputs - can anyone help?

I saw a question like this - but I could not implement the range function they described in a way that works with shuffle. Thanks.

Comment: How large? Depending on the answer this is trivial to impossible.

Comment: What's going wrong? How big are your inputs?

Comment: What do you want to do with the result of `shuffle`?

Comment: What is it that you're actually having trouble with?

Answer (score 4):

To get a random permutation of the range `[0, n)` in a memory efficient manner; you could use [`numpy.random.permutation()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.permutation.html#numpy.random.permutation):

```
import numpy as np

numbers = np.random.permutation(n)
```

If you need only small fraction of values from the range e.g., to get `k` random values from `[0, n)` range:

```
import random
from functools import partial

def sample(n, k):
    # assume n is much larger than k
    randbelow = partial(random.randrange, n)
    # from random.py
    result = [None] * k
    selected = set()
    selected_add = selected.add
    for i in range(k):
        j = randbelow()
        while j in selected:
            j = randbelow()
        selected_add(j)
        result[i] = j
    return result


print(sample(10**100, 10))
```

Comment: There is really no need for the non-standard module NumPy, here: the standard `array` module (see my answer) makes the list of numbers have the same memory footprint as with NumPy.

Comment: I removed the unnecessary use of indices and None-list initialization. I also simplified `random.randint()` into the more appropriate `random.randrange()`, which was designed explicitly for this case. I also gave the function a proper docstring.

Comment: @EOL: I've changed `randrange()` but the rest might not be appropriate.

Comment: Initializing an array with None values that are later erased, and appending elements to a list through indexing is not the customary way of building a list in Python. So, this code is less legible than the usual `result = []; … result.append()`. There are also many other reasons for preferring the Pythonic version to your original C-like version: (1) `result = [None]*k` makes me think that `None` has some meaning in your code, whereas it is actually irrelevant; (2) Index `i` is an additional, unnecessary variable that has to be parsed by the reader; (3) `result[i] = …` is really an append…

Comment: @EOL: `[None]*size` is a standard Python idiom to preallocate a list. The code is from stdlib's `random` module. It is optimized for performance.

Comment: @EOL: `numpy` arrays are the standard way to perform computations on large amount of data in Python. The have much more functionality and faster than `array.array`. You need *a reason not to use* them for numerical computations in Python.

Comment: If NumPy is available, then yes, it should be used. However, there are many reasons to give a solution with the `array` module: (1) the `array` module is *standard*, whereas `numpy` is not necessarily available; (2) *as memory-efficient* as NumPy for representing arrays; (3) there are *no numerical calculations in this question*; (4) the *standard* `random.shuffle` works for shuffling the array; (5) the standard-modules approach is not much slower than the NumPy approach (with 1 million elements).

Answer (score 3):

If you don't need the full list of numbers (and if you are getting billions, its hard to imagine why you would need them all), you might be better off taking a `random.sample` of your number range, rather than shuffling them all. In Python 3, `random.sample` can work on a `range` object too, so your memory use can be quite modest.

For example, here's code that will sample ten thousand random numbers from a range up to whatever maximum value you specify. It should require only a relatively small amount of memory beyond the 10000 result values, even if your maximum is 100 billion (or whatever enormous number you want):

```
import random

def get10kRandomNumbers(maximum):
    pop = range(1, maximum+1) # this is memory efficient in Python 3
    sample = random.sample(pop, 10000)
    return sample
```

Alas, this doesn't work as nicely in Python 2, since `xrange` objects don't allow maximum values greater than the system's integer type can hold.

Comment: +1: but it won't work on Python 3 either: `OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C ssize_t` (due to `len(population)` call inside `sample()`)

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: Hmm, it works for me on Python 3.3.0. Which version did you get that error on? I got that on Python 2.7 with `xrange`, but Python 3's `range` has been given some enhancements.

Comment: Ah, the limit varies depending on whether you're on a 64-bit OS and using 64-bit aware Python or not. So `ssize_t` is 64 bits on some systems, but 32 bits on others. I'm using 64-bit Python on a 64-bit Windows 7 OS, and my tests used a range of 100 billion (1e11) which only needs 37 or 38 bits. `range` does break for me at 1e19 (one quintillion!).

Comment: @Blckknght: Very good solution, within the limits indicated! You mean *`random.sample`* breaks at *`range(10**19)`* (*10* quintillion!), though. :)

Comment: @EOL: Yeah, I typoed the 10 quintillion. To be more precise, 2**63 (9223372036854775807, ~9.2 quintillion) is the first value to have a problem, and it's `len` that breaks with the `OverflowError` J.F.Sebasital quoted above.

Comment: @Blckknght: `get10kRandomNumbers(10**100) -> OverflowError` then and now (Python 3.6)

Answer (score 0):

An important point to note is that it will be **impossible** for a computer **to have the list of numbers in memory if it is larger than a few billion elements**: its memory footprint becomes larger than the typical RAM size (as it takes about 4 GB for 1 billion 32-bit numbers).

In the question, `val` is a `long` integer, which seems to indicate that you are indeed using more than a billion integer, so this cannot be done conveniently in memory (i.e., shuffling will be slow, as the operating system will swap).

That said, if the number of elements is small enough (let's say smaller than 0.5 billion), then a list of elements can fit in memory thanks to the **compact representation offered by the `array` module**, and be shuffled. This can be done with the standard module `array`:

```
import array, random
numbers = array.array('I', xrange(10**8))  # or 'L', if the number of bytes per item (numbers.itemsize) is too small with 'I'
random.shuffle(numbers)
```